# Displaying image in a div from controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am saving an image to public folder and now I want to display it inside a defined **`<div class="logo">`** how can that be achieved?

Controller:

```
public function testing(Request $request) {
    if($request->hasFile('img'));
    {
        $image = Input::file('img');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('images/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200)->save($path);
        $file = $request->file('img');
        return response()->file($file);
    }
}
```

JS:

```
function submitImage(){
    var fd = new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]);
        fd.append( 'img', $('#img') );

$.ajax({
      url:'template',
      data: fd,
      dataType:'json',
      async:false,
      type:'post',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
    });
}
```

Blade:

```
<form id="upload_form" action="{{ action('BuilderController@testing') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input name="img" id="img" class="form-control filestyle margin images" data-input="false" type="file" data-buttonText="Upload Logo" data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="submitImage();" />
</form>
<div class="logo">
    <img class="images" id="image" src="#" alt="Your Logo"/>
</div>
```

So I want to change **`src="#"`** to a path where image has been saved such as **`"C://xampp/htdocs/laravel/public/image/1.jpg"`**

Comment: Why not send a JSON response with the filename and change the src of **`#image`** with the filename using the **`public_path()`** method

Comment: Can you show me code of how can that be achieved? So I can accept as an answer

Comment: Can you dump the response you are getting?

Comment: Is `url:'template',` the right url? I only ask because it' seems to be different to the action in your form

Comment: what you mean by it being different? and it should be right as it runs on localhost/template

Comment: just checking that template is the right url :)

Comment: So what you want me to do?

Comment: And how you want me to do?

Comment: Nothing, I was just asking a question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the`return` in you controller method to be:

```
return ['url' => url('images/' . $filename)];
```

Then add a `success` method to your `ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'template',
    data: fd,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    type: 'post',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#image").attr("src", data.url)
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller code to

```
public function testing(Request $request) {
    if($request->hasFile('img'));
    {
        $image = Input::file('img');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('images/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200)->save($path);
        $file = $request->file('img');
        $response = [];
        $response['name'] = $path;
        return json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

and in your JS add a success code which would change the url of the image

```
$.ajax({
      url:'template',
      data: fd,
      dataType:'json',
      async:false,
      type:'post',
      success: function (data) {
         var img_loc = JSON.parse(data).name;
         $("#image").attr('src', img_loc);
      },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
    });
}
```